# How to modify data after replicate in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to edit values after making duplicate rows in Pandas.
I want to edit only one column ("code"), but i see that since it has duplicates , it will affect the entire rows.

Is there any method to first create duplicates and then modify data only of duplicates created ?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('so.xlsx',index=False)

a = df['code'] == 1234
b = df[a]
df=df.append(b)
print('\n\nafter replicate')
print(df)
```

Current output after making duplicates is as below:

```
  coun  code name
0    A  123   AR
1    F  123   AD
2    N  7   AR
3    I  0   AA
4    T  10   AS
2    N  7   AR
3    I  7   AA
```

Now I expect to change values only on duplicates created , in this case bottom two rows. But now I see the indexes are duplicated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the duplicate indices by using the ignore_index argument to append.

```
df=df.append(b, ignore_index=True)
```

You may also find it easier to modify your data in b, before appending it to the frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('so.xlsx',index=False)

a = df['code'] == 3
b = df[a]
b["region"][2] = "N"
df=df.append(b, ignore_index=True)
print('\n\nafter replicate')
print(df)
```

Comment: Many thanks ! it worked. Also [:2] bought me to the last two rows I needed.